# Blender crashing whenever I render and click user preferences CYCLES 2.79B

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Blender crashes when I render a picture, when I view port render, click the camera render tab, and user preferences while on Cycles. Switching engines still crashes blender.

Confident Blender was using my GPU but can't really check. 
I've tried to select user preferences by clicking on the bottom left but still crashes. Not sure if this means anything but Maya and After Effects crashes on start up, Photoshop works fine though.

PC Specs:

Intel i7-7700k, Nvidia 1070, Corsair 16gbs of ram, Windows 10

Blender 2.79B

Comment: Hello and welcome. "*Not sure if this means anything but Maya and After Effects crashes on start up*" That has to tell you something about the stability and health of your system. As it stands this is a system maintenance question, not about Blender hence off topic here.

Comment: @duarte Anything you can recommend? I've updated my GPU drivers last night but still nothing. Tried re installing 2.79b and other older versions but no old ones would open. I've thought it was my GPU too, but my PC says its working properly and runs games the same still.

Comment: I'd say do a full system install with Microsoft clean OS images, then do a clean driver install from NVidia. If problems persist you probably have hardware related  issues.